# PHP string to float bug?

Tags: php

So, I got this:

```
$a = "149.45";
var_dump($a);
```

gives

```
string(6) "149.45"
```

now

```
$b = $a * 100;
var_dump($b);
```

so far so good:

```
float(14945)
```

and now

```
$i = (int)$b;
var_dump($i);
```

What the ...?

```
int(14944)
```

Tested on PHP 5.2.17 (on CentOS) and PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 (On ubuntu).
Can anyone tell me if this is a known bug?
Can anyone test it on a newer PHP version?

### EDIT

OK, I got it, float binary representation aproximation error. For my code I already used `round()`.
But why then

```
$a = 149.45;
$b = 100 * $a;
var_dump($b)
printf('%.10f', $b);
```

gives

```
float(14945)
14945.0000000000
```

? Why that string is not parsed just as `149.45` is parsed?

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug in your understanding of how floating point works. The "14945" value isn't going to be *exactly* 14945 - it'll be something slightly smaller. See lots of other floating point questions on SO for more information.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustration of what @Jon said:

```
$a = "149.45";
$b = $a * 100;
var_dump($b);
printf("%.50f", $b);
```

result

```
14944.99999999999818101059645414352416992187500000000000000
```

"14945" is just a *string representation* of the above number, not that number itself.